# React Problem returning an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on creating a list of cards that get their info from a Backend component, the problem comes when I'm returning an url variable inside the objects, but when trying to use it appears null.
This would be my code:
**Backend** The problem is in url var.

```
export async function getAllIDs(){
  const q = query(collection(db, "Books"));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  let array= [];
  let it=0;
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    var data = {};
    //console.log(doc.data().Image);
    getDownloadURL(ref(storageRef, doc.data().Image))
    .then((url) => {
    // Or inserted into an <img> element
      data.url=url;
      
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  }); 
    

    data.id=doc.id;
    data.Title=doc.data().Title;
    data.Summary=doc.data().Summary;
    array[it]=data;
    it++;
    //console.log(data);
    
  });
  //console.log(array);
  return array;

}
```

**List data**

```
render() {
    let data = [];
    data = this.state.data;
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <Box sx={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleScroll("left")}>Left</Button>
        <Box
          ref={this.scrollContainerRef}
          style={{
            //flexWrap: "wrap",
            justifyContent: "space-around",
            overflow: "hidden",
            width: "70%",
            overflowX: "scroll",
            flexGrow: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ flexWrap: "nowrap" }}>
            {data.map((data, index) => {
              const { pp, url, Title, Summary } = data;
              console.log(pp);
              return (
                <Grid item>
                  <Card sx={{ width: 300 }}>
                    <CardMedia
                      sx={{ height: 140 }}
                      component="img"
                      image={url}
                      title="green iguana"
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                        {Title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        {Summary}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
          </Grid>
        </Box>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleScroll("right")}>Right</Button>
      </Box>
    );
  }
```

I have coded some logs to try to understand the array,
The first array written is from the start of the render(this array of objects is correct because each object has a url variable)
The second part of the image is the logs of each object at the moment I am using them [(as you can see the url is not connected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qksrP.png)

I think the problems could come from the moment each object is created and depends if I added that var to the object inside the `getdownloadURL`
I tried adding: `data.try="working";` inside and outside the `getdownloadURL` function and it only works when adding outside.

I don't know how to solve this error, it seems that it could be how the objects are created but they are returned correctly, the objects change when trying to use it in the obj.map

Comment: You're modifying `data` in the `forEach` loop inside of an async call (`then`) but not awaiting promise resolution so your code moves on to the lines after `getDownloadURL` without waiting for that line to finish. I'd recommend you update the function to use `async`/`await` and properly wait for promise resolution before returning.